# XPath for image in popup

Tags: xpath, scrapy, xpath-2.0

I'm using Scrapy to crawl a webpage. I get the XPath selectors by using an xpath Chrome extension, which works fine. I'm getting everything I want on the product page like description, price etc.

If I click on a small image of an item, the big image of that item pops up, and I want to crawl this big image. But the Xpath I'm using for this big image isn't fetching anything. Also, when I viewed the source code, it shows that it uses a javascript function to load these pop up images. Is there a way to fetch these images?

```
start_urls = ['http://www.flipkart.com/nokia-lumia-620/p/itmdgkwywkmaa2w4?pid=MOBDGH6AKH9ERJAF']

description = hxs.select('/html/body/div[@class=" fkart fksk-body line  "]/div[@id="fk-mainbody-id"]/div[@class="fk-content fksk-content enable-compare line"]/div[@class="fk-mproduct fk-mproduct-mobile "]/div[@class="mprod-section unit"]/div[@id="topsection"]/div[@class="mprod-summary lastUnit"]/div[@class="mprod-summary-title fksk-mprod-summary-title"]/h1/text()').extract()
price = hxs.select('/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/span/text()').extract()

image_urls = hxs.select('/html/body/div[@class="fk-ui-dialog fk-popup"]/div[@class="window alpha30 window-absolute"]/div[@class="content"]/div[@class="dialog-body"]/div[@id="pp-large-images-popup"]/div[@class="main-container"]/div[@class="pp-carousel-bd"]/div[@class="visible-image-large fk-text-center"]/img[@id="visible-image-large"]').extract()
```

Result :

```
{'description': [u'Nokia Lumia 620'],
 'image_urls': [],
 'price': u'14999'}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the list of image urls for the small thumbnails you can use this XPath:

```
//div[@class="thumbs thumbs-small"]/img/@src
```

You can derive the urls of the big images from the urls of the thumbnail images. Just replace `40x40` to `275x275` and you will get the url of the big images.

Comment: Thanks a lot! that worked! but just wondering if there is a better way to do this, since I have to do fetch these images from other websites as well, with different structures and naming.

Comment: If the loading of the big images are done by javascript, then the urls cannot be retrieved by an xpath expression once the page is loaded as they are not present in the DOM of the HTML page, but only after certain user interaction. (e.g. hover over of the thumbnail, etc.). Building a generic scraper for such images is a rather complex problem and no single xpath will give you the results.

Comment: ok, thanks! In that case I hope this replacement thing works out with other such websites as well :)